# dajngo pagination for products, problem with pagination when query

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm working on a Django project for building a website, and I'm facing an issue when filtering through a search bar by name; the pagination is not working correctly.

When filtering

```
def mart(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    temperature = request.GET.get('temperature')

    if temperature is None:
        temperature = 150

    products = Product.objects.all()
    
    if query:
        products = products.filter(Q(name__icontains=query))
        for product in products:
            latest_log = Log.objects.filter(product_uuid=product).order_by('-date').first()
            if latest_log:
                temp = latest_log.course_temp
                product.temperature = temp
            else:
                product.temperature = 0
        products = sorted(products, key=lambda x:x.temperature, reverse=True)

        paginator = Paginator(products, 20)
        page_number = request.GET.get('page')
        page_products = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        product_info_list = []


        for product in page_products:
            latest_log = Log.objects.filter(product_uuid=product,course_temp__lte=temperature).order_by('-date').first()
            all_productbadges = Productbadge.objects.filter(product_uuid=product)

            badges_urls = []
            if all_productbadges:
                for productbadge in all_productbadges:
                    badge_id = productbadge.badge_id
                    badge_instance = Badge.objects.filter(label=badge_id).first()
                    if badge_instance:
                        badge_url = badge_instance.url
                        badges_urls.append(badge_url)

            if latest_log:
                product_info = {
                    'product': product,
                    'latest_log': latest_log,
                    'badges_urls': badges_urls
                }
                product_info_list.append(product_info)
        print("@@@@@@@@@")
        print(page_products.next_page_number)
        context = {'product_info_list': product_info_list, 'page_products': page_products}
        return render(request, 'courses/mart.html', context=context)

    

    paginator = Paginator(products, 20)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_products = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    product_info_list = []

    for product in page_products:
        latest_log = Log.objects.filter(product_uuid=product,course_temp__lte=temperature).order_by('-date').first()
        all_productbadges = Productbadge.objects.filter(product_uuid=product)

        badges_urls = []
        if all_productbadges:
            for productbadge in all_productbadges:
                badge_id = productbadge.badge_id
                badge_instance = Badge.objects.filter(label=badge_id).first()
                if badge_instance:
                    badge_url = badge_instance.url
                    badges_urls.append(badge_url)

        if latest_log:
            product_info = {
                'product': product,
                'latest_log': latest_log,
                'badges_urls': badges_urls
            }
            product_info_list.append(product_info)
    context = {'product_info_list': product_info_list, 'page_products': page_products}
    return render(request, 'courses/mart.html', context=context)
```

When filtering the pagination show me the options but when I click on "SIGUIENTE" (next) the page showed is the SECOND page for the all products, basically the filter is gone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72WSi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Z3t.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQmWt.png)

After click on the "SIGUIENTE" the page showed is the page 2 from the total products and not the filtered
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtH98.png)

Thanks for you support

A help with the code for the iterator paginator for query search.

Answer (score 0):

There is no param of query when you are navigating to the second page which is
`127.0.0.1:8000/courses/?page=2`. Filtering is done only if `q` is passed on params by according to your code, I guess query is being passed for `page=1` request, but not from `2, 3, 4,... pages`, try adding `q` param for the remaining pages to apply the filter.

The request for second page could be

```
127.0.0.1:8000/courses/?q=medicina&page=2
```